# Can't compile when using wrap figure

Tags: lyx

I'm using lyx with a hebrew package (using xetex). It seems that I can't compile when inserting a wrap-figure, and I can't understand why.

Here are the errors:
[image]

And here is the latex code, taken from code preview pane:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.1-1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[11pt,english,hebrew]{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9,cp1255]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=0.5cm,rmargin=0.5cm,headheight=0.5cm,headsep=0.5cm,footskip=2cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.5\columnwidth}%

\caption{\L{\protect\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{1}}}

\end{wrapfigure}%


\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hebrew (bidi) is complex and wrapfigure too. Without a small, complete example problems are very difficult to impossible to debug.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Can you specify what counts as complete? The document is empty except this figure, so it's isolated. Is there any more logs I should add to the OP?

Comment: A complete document start with \documentclass and ends with \end{document} and can be copied and then compiled unchanged.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for your input, OP has been edited

Comment: `\usepackage[latin9,cp1255]{inputenc}` doesn't make any sense, your files can't have two encodings at the same time. Why don't you use xelatex or lualatex for hebrew?

Comment: @Suspicious_1 can you please also post a simple .lyx file? I'm especially interested since I wonder if LyX has a bug (if it is trying to load `inputenc` with two encodings). For more information on minimal examples and how to post a .lyx file, see here: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: @scottkosty,This weird behavior  happens  when you set the document language as Hebrew and export the file with pdflatex. Also i should probably mention that the graphics should be inserted in the outer frame of the figure inset and not inside the caption.

Comment: According to your question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668673/how-do-i-write-only-x-lines-when-inserting-figure-wrap it seems that you solved your problem. Can you post an answer?

Comment: @UdiFogiel Unfortunately the 'fix' was just to delete my distro of lyx and the compiler, and move to a different one. For any future hebrew users - I moved on from Meital distribution with miktex to manual installation of Tex Live and Lyx

Comment: @UdiFogiel thanks, I can reproduce that.

Comment: For anyone curious, LyX fixed the issue about loading inputenc with multiple encodings at https://git.lyx.org/?p=lyx.git;a=commit;h=9716e796