# How do I write only X lines when inserting figure wrap?

Tags: lyx

My problem is that I want to write only a certain amount of lines/text next to a figure wrap, and then to drop below the image and keep writing as regular. Right now it looks like this:

[image]

The lyx editor looks like this:

[image]

Ideally, I'd want to write only 2-3 lines, and then to keep writing below.
I assume the solution is simple, but I haven't find anything online
Thanks in advance

Comment: Ordinary text with wrapfig should be no problem.  Lists (itemize or enumerate) not so much.  Paracol is an optional approach, but you have to manually break paragraphs.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'm not intrested in lists, just to be able to break out of the wrap, and go back into writing below the image

Comment: It looks like you inserted the graphics file inside the caption, it should be in the outer frame.

Comment: @UdiFogiel Thank you, I moved it to the outside frame. Still, haven't found a way to "break" out of the wrap and write as usual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add some vertical space depending on your image size and the number of lines you want to have beside you figure. To add a vertical space in LyX go to `Insert->Formatting->Vertical Space...`, change the spacing to custom and specify the proper length.

Below the caption but inside the wrap figure add negative vertical space, this space will reduce the number of lines that will be printed beside the figure.

Now you will need to correct the vertical space below to figure. To do that, insert a positive vertical space below the last line that should be beside your figure (after the second היי in your case).

In the end you should have something resembling the following image:

[image]

Which should give you the following output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Just a couple of questions: 1) is the negative vspace necessary? When removing it, I got the same result. 2) Is there a quick way to determine how much vspace to insert? say the image's height is X pixels and I want to write Y lines of text (size 11)

Comment: Glad to help :) 1) I think it depend on the dimension of the image, in my example if i remove the negative vertical space the lower "היי"'s are positioned vertically the same, but to the left of the figure. 2) the vertical space is not only depends on the image, but also the size of the caption, the vertical space between the caption and the figure and vertical space between the wrap float and the text. I'm not sure how to evaluate all of these dimensions. You can open a separate question about this topic.

Comment: If this solution is suffice you might want to accept it, this way the bot will stop pop it once in a while to remind people this question is still open.